# Random reboot during switching between apps

Tags: android-10, ram, motorola

My device:
Motorola One, Android 10

During clicking on a link in WhatsApp (default browser is Brave) Android rebooted accidentally. This random reboots happens from time to time (several times a week). Backtrace may suggest that it was caused by heap corruption (LogHeapCorruption).

Is there any way to find the root cause of an issue?

```
05-24 19:04:47.038  2190 15997 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://....pl/... flg=0x14002000 cmp=com.brave.browser/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity (has extras)} from uid 10126
05-24 19:04:47.153  2190  8581 I WindowManager:   SURFACE show Surface(name=com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper)/@0x71f13fc on display:0: com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper
05-24 19:04:47.154  2190  8581 I WindowManager:   SURFACE show Surface(name=Splash Screen com.brave.browser)/@0xe5f66a9 on display:0: Splash Screen com.brave.browser
05-24 19:04:47.754  2190  2268 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 2268 (android.display), pid 2190 (system_server)
05-24 19:04:48.002 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-24 19:04:48.002 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'motorola/deen/deen_sprout:10/QPKS30.54-22-21/417dd1:user/release-keys'
05-24 19:04:48.003 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : Revision: 'PVT1'
05-24 19:04:48.003 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2021-05-24 19:04:48+0200
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : pid: 2190, tid: 2268, name: android.display  >>> system_server <<<
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : uid: 1000
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Check failed: found_virtual Didn't find oat method index for virtual method: void android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator.<init>(android.content.Context)'
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000008dc  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007d805d58f0
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x4  6d49000000000000  x5  6d49000000000000  x6  6d49000000000000  x7  000000000080496d
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  5a781b4ca14965bb  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x12 fffffff0ffffffdf  x13 0000000008e584c8  x14 0000000000000008  x15 0000225fa48f30e4
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007e0d44d8c0  x17 0000007e0d42b020  x18 0000007d1d8f4000  x19 000000000000088e
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x20 00000000000008dc  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000007c94c4fa00  x23 0000007d880e864e
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000007d880c85c0  x25 0000007d885ff000  x26 0000007d8867a258  x27 0000007d885ff000
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007d805d5990
05-24 19:04:48.008 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007d805d58d0  lr  0000007e0d3dff88  pc  0000007e0d3dffb4
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000082fb4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160) (BuildId: 4cd97724e0ae0bf213b33eacb7bfbbe8)
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000004b5064  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2268) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000000000000c5b4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+608) (BuildId: 9b1ba30f299c594bb54939a36936205f)
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000000000028e804  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Verification::LogHeapCorruption(art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>, art::MemberOffset, art::mirror::Object*, bool) const+1404) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 000000000021d184  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::MarkNonMoving(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*, art::mirror::Object*, art::MemberOffset)+148) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000001433c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ReadBarrier::Mark(art::mirror::Object*)+520) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.382 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000146e44  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL16FindOatMethodForEPNS_9ArtMethodENS_11PointerSizeEPb.llvm.11041615836067245275+108) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.383 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 0000000000146c74  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::GetOatQuickMethodHeader(unsigned long)+280) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.383 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000004d6c88  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12StackVisitor9WalkStackILNS0_16CountTransitionsE0EEEvb+400) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.383 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 00000000004f4430  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+472) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.383 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000050e828  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+820) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.390 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 00000000005078c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+456) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.390 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000506b18  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+1296) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.390 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000004b4d38  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1456) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.390 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 000000000000c5b4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+608) (BuildId: 9b1ba30f299c594bb54939a36936205f)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 0000000000147038  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL16FindOatMethodForEPNS_9ArtMethodENS_11PointerSizeEPb.llvm.11041615836067245275+608) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 0000000000146c74  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::GetOatQuickMethodHeader(unsigned long)+280) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 00000000001ee960  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::FaultManager::IsInGeneratedCode(siginfo*, void*, bool)+896) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 00000000001ee2b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*)+92) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 0000000000004dc4  /system/bin/app_process64 (art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*)+588) (BuildId: 5f77a287bef8ee816eb6bce4880d182d)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 0000000000000690  [vdso] (__kernel_rt_sigreturn)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 000000000057f6d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artInstanceOfFromCode+88) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 000000000013795c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_check_instance_of+12) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 00000000016f5820  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.isReceivingBroadcastLocked+464) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 0000000001416668  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.am.OomAdjuster.computeOomAdjLocked+2008) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 000000000070a8b0  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.am.OomAdjuster.updateOomAdjLocked+1264) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 0000000000b8c7fc  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord.updateProcessInfo+332) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 0000000000b8c108  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.am.ProcessRecord.onStartActivity+312) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 0000000000ddd5b0  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$VY87MmFWaCLMkNa2qHGaPrThyrI.accept+240) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 0000000000b7cb24  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke+5556) (BuildId: bcbbf6dbefd89fff71e2c4b30159b42d915c3070)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 0000000000b7ee54  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke+836) (BuildId: bcbbf6dbefd89fff71e2c4b30159b42d915c3070)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 0000000000b51b9c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run+76) (BuildId: bcbbf6dbefd89fff71e2c4b30159b42d915c3070)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 0000000000738b7c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+76) (BuildId: bcbbf6dbefd89fff71e2c4b30159b42d915c3070)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 000000000073c48c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+2140) (BuildId: bcbbf6dbefd89fff71e2c4b30159b42d915c3070)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #34 pc 000000000073abfc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.HandlerThread.run+588) (BuildId: bcbbf6dbefd89fff71e2c4b30159b42d915c3070)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #35 pc 0000000001392554  /system/framework/oat/arm64/services.odex (com.android.server.ServiceThread.run+100) (BuildId: dc7af8324d4ef4f07322522c8e9638a72ad82930)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #36 pc 0000000000137334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #37 pc 000000000014606c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #38 pc 00000000004accd0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.391 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #39 pc 00000000004add64  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.392 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #40 pc 00000000004edb00  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176) (BuildId: 0dfc48458ebe469ada07dc81b5a44d76)
05-24 19:04:48.392 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #41 pc 00000000000e205c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: 4cd97724e0ae0bf213b33eacb7bfbbe8)
05-24 19:04:48.392 17729 17729 F DEBUG   :       #42 pc 0000000000084af0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 4cd97724e0ae0bf213b33eacb7bfbbe8)
05-24 19:04:51.521 13310 13310 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 19:04:51.521 13310 13310 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.brave.browser, PID: 13310
05-24 19:04:51.521 13310 13310 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-24 19:04:51.586   830   865 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
05-24 19:04:51.586   830   865 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.apps.fitness, PID: 830
05-24 19:04:51.586   830   865 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
05-24 19:04:51.598  2756  2756 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 19:04:51.598  2756  2756 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.phone, PID: 2756
05-24 19:04:51.598  2756  2756 E AndroidRuntime: DeadSystemException: The system died; earlier logs will point to the root cause
```

Comment: Do you know the person who has sent the link to you personally? Because a link that makes a web browser to cause a heap corruption may be a malicious link and the heap corruption was an attempt to exploit a vulnerability and execute virus code. The other alternative would be a hardware RAM defect causing this effect.

Comment: @Robert This link was a regular link to well known website. So after reboot of my phone I was able to successfully open that link. So it was accidental thing. Is it possible to that RAM is corrupted (broken) physically in my phone?

Comment: A physically damaged RAM is possible but that it only affects brave would be very unusual. Especially after a reboot locations in memory should be totally different.